# zend2 adding another controller to application

Tags: controller, routes, zend-framework2

I'm working on a ZendFramework2.4-project.
I just got started an filled the IndexController of a standard skeleton application with some code and thought of another controller in the same application.

No new modul, just a second Controller to keep code seperated.

Of course I read the documentation at
[Zend2: Routing and Controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)

But whatever I'm doing, I always get something like 404 not found.
I get no route to the second controller.

When I read modul.config.php, I think, there's nothing to do in here....am I right or wrong?

```
// The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
```

But doing nothing but implementing the controller doesn't work too...

Is there something wrong with the documentation?

Maybe you have a hint...

Okay:
I've tried to both of your examples you gave.

My module.config.php now looks like this:

```
 'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'Am'    => 'Application\Controller\AmController'
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(                  

        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'arznei' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:controller][/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Am',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    )
),
```

Imho I think this should work for //myServer/ (first rule 'home') and for any other uri like //myServer/myController/myAction/25 .

But it doesn't.

For the second route I always get '404 object not found'.
Maybe there is another option going wrong in the configuration of apache2.
Seems the rewrite is incorrect in some way.

The rewrite module is loaded and enabled as far as I can see at the moment. I'm going to check out that issue.

You both were right.

I found a mistake hidden deeply in the apache2-configuration that blocked precise rewriting for the upper configurations.

The main thing is to make sure that the option "AllowOverride" is set to "All" and "FollowSymLinks" must be allowed too for the "public" directory of your application.

In my special case with an openSUSE-Server I wrote a directory definition in /etc/apache2/default-server.conf:

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/myDirectory/public">
Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple controllers in a single module, but you need to set up your routing to identify when to use which controller.  Since you have referenced Akrabat's album module in your question, I'll use it to illustrate:

The album module tutorial shows how to create four actions: `indexAction`, `addAction`, `deleteAction` and `editAction`; all in the same controller.  Let's say, however, that since `index` deals with collections of albums and the other actions each manipulate a single album; we have decided to have two controllers: `AlbumsController` (which would include `indexAction`) and `AlbumController` (which would include the `addAction`, `deleteAction` and `editAction`).

In your module.config.php file, you will then need to invoke the second controller and create an alternate route to point to it:

```
 return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
             'Album\Controller\Albums' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumsController', // added second controller
         ),
     ),

     // The following section is new and should be added to your file
     'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'album' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'add',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),

             // add route to new controller
             'albums' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/albums[/:action]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Albums',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),

 // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use these steps to add a controller in your application

1. Create a controller class inside `/module/Yourmodule/src/Yourmodule/Controller` which will be something like

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Yourmodule\Controller;

   use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

   /**
    *
    * @author user
    *        
    */
   class YourController extends AbstractActionController {

       public function indexAction() {}

       // .... other codes

   }
   ```

   and name it `YourController.php`.
2. Create view for the action `/module/Yourmodule/view/yourmodule/yourontroller/index.phtml`

> Remember the view file name should be same as the function name except **Action** here `indexAction` => `index.phtml`

3. Add route, edit the `module.config.php`

   ```
   return array(
       'router' => array(
           'routes' => array(                  

               'your-test-route' => array(
                   'type' => 'Literal',
                   'options' => array(
                       'route'    => '/your-test-uri',
                       'defaults' => array(
                           'controller' => 'Yourmodule\Controller\YourController',
                           'action' => 'index'
                       ),
                   ),
               ),

               // ... other routes 
           )
       ),

       'controllers' => array(
           'invokables' => array(              
               'Yourmodule\Controller\YourController' => 'Yourmodule\Controller\YourController'
           ),
       ),
       'view_manager' => array(
           'template_path_stack' => array(
               __DIR__ . '/../view',
           ),
       ),

       // ... other codes
   );
   ```
4. Now run in your web browser http://yoursite.com/your-test-uri

Answer (score 0):

You both were right.

I found a mistake hidden deeply in the apache2-configuration that blocked precise rewriting for the upper configurations.

The main thing is to make sure that the option "AllowOverride" is set to "All" and "FollowSymLinks" must be allowed too for the "public" directory of your application.

In my special case with an openSUSE-Server I wrote a directory definition in /etc/apache2/default-server.conf:

```html
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/myDirectory/public">
Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

The place to do this is different in linux-distributions so you have to take a look, were you have to place this... in most cases something like "httpd.conf".

This solved my problem.

Thanks for the important hints about the router-configuration!